# MATCH and reference to multiple cells in Excel conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using `MATCH` and conditional formatting to mark meetings in a calendar in Excel like:

```
=MATCH(DATE($B$2;8;B7); $T$7:$T$30; 0)
```

What I want:

- Mark dates with different colours, depending on in which country the meeting takes place. SE should be blue, NL should be yellow.

What I have:

- Currently all cells get marked with blue, regardless of the country (see image)

How can I incorporate the country information in the inputs to get different colours for different countries?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The formula you have does not return SE or NL, you need to add an INDEX function to the front to make this happen.

```
(=INDEX($U$7:$U$30,MATCH(DATE($B$2;8;B7);$T$7:$T$30;0)))
```

This will find the matching SE or NL with the date you looked up, you can then test this in the conditional formatting to pick the appropriate colour.

```
 (=INDEX($U$7:$U$30,MATCH(DATE($B$2;8;B7);$T$7:$T$30;0))="SE")
```

Will allow you to check if the answer is SE, if it is set the colour to Blue.

```
 (=INDEX($U$7:$U$30,MATCH(DATE($B$2;8;B7);$T$7:$T$30;0))="NL")
```

Will allow you to check if the answer is NL, if it is set the colour to Yellow.

Comment: Thank you! What more do I need to add to test it in the conditional formatting? I do not get it to work properly..

Comment: Can you mark it as an accepted solution, as it works and has answered the question? Thanks.

Comment: @Helena did you notice that you got +5 reputation points, because someone gave you a +1 on your question? When you accept the answer, you will get another +2 reputation point and Rob Anthony will get +15 reputation for his answer